# Use this.userId in publish functions

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code is giving the error below:

```
Meteor.publish('myCol', function (age) {
  if (!this.userId) return;
  if (Meteor.user().profile.hasOwnProperty('gotNoAge')) return; //<=== error line
  console.log('publishing for age: ' + age);

    return MyCol.find({age: age}, {
      fields: {
        myField: true
      }, limit: 1
    });

});
```

> Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.

I tried changing the "error line" to the following for no avail. 
`if (Meteor.users.find({_id:this.userId}).profile.hasOwnProperty('gotNoAge')) return;`

Any suggestins? thx

Comment: Try with `findOne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Meteor.publish('myCol', function (age) {
  if (!this.userId) return;
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  if (user.profile.hasOwnProperty('gotNoAge')) return; 
  console.log('publishing for age: ' + age);

  return MyCol.find({age: age}, {
    fields: {
      myField: true
    }, limit: 1
  });
});
```